# Python subprocess.Popen() doesn't show correct stdout subprocess.call()

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

When I execute the following script in Windows 7, it shows a different stdout format for the two cases. The first stdout shows an inline string, and the second one shows the same as executing the command in Windows cmd.exe. What is wrong with my code?

---

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]
print('STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout)) #first stdout

subprocess.call('dir', shell=True) #second stdout
```

---

**first stdout**

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProject/spython_to_cmd_communication.py
STDOUT:b' C \xb5\xe5\xb6\xf3\xc0\xcc\xba\xea\xc0\xc7 \xba\xbc\xb7\xfd: Windows7\r\n \xba\xbc\xb7\xfd \xc0\xcf\xb7\xc3 \xb9\xf8\xc8\xa3: 8623-6624\r\n\r\n C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\xb5\xf0\xb7\xba\xc5\xcd\xb8\xae\r\n\r\n2017-04-26  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:44    <DIR>          .\r\n2017-04-26  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:44    <DIR>          ..\r\n2017-04-26  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:44    <DIR>          .idea\r\n2017-04-20  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:03             2,652  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:29             4,664 listing_stock_code_business.py\r\n2017-04-26  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:44               241 python_to_cmd_communication.py\r\n2017-04-20  \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:24             1,780   \xbf\xc0\xc8\xc4 08:24    <DIR>          __pycache__\r\n               4\xb0\xb3 \xc6\xc4\xc0\xcf               9,337 \xb9\xd9\xc0\xcc\xc6\xae\r\n               4\xb0\xb3 \xb5\xf0\xb7\xba\xc5\xcd\xb8\xae  38,024,884,224 \xb9\xd9\xc0\xcc\xc6\xae \xb3\xb2\xc0\xbd\r\n'
 C ����̺��� ����: Windows7
 ���� �Ϸ� ��ȣ: 8
```

**second stdout**

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\python_to_cmd_communication���͸�

2017-04-26  ���� 08:44    <DIR>          .
2017-04-26  ���� 08:44    <DIR>          ..
2017-04-26  ���� 08:44    <DIR>          .idea
2017-04-26  ���� 08:44               241 python_to_cmd_communication.py
2017-04-20  ���� 08:24    <DIR>          __pycache__
               4�� ����               9,337 ����Ʈ
               4�� ���͸�  38,024,884,224 ����Ʈ ����

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `stdout` is a file-like object, not a string. You need to read strings from it, rather than converting the object to a single string.

Comment: `subprocess.call` doesn't redirect `stdout` to a pipe, so cmd.exe writes 16-bit wide characters directly to the console. The first case redirects `stdout` to a pipe, so cmd.exe encodes the output written to the pipe using the current console codepage. You appear to have the console set to codepage 936 (simplified Chinese), so you need to decode the output as `stdout.decode('cp936')`.

Comment: I suggest configuring the console to use a font that supports your preferred locale, so the output isn't filled with replacement characters like "����".

Comment: Thank you all comments. Problem is solved by adding '.decode('cp949') print('STDOUT:}'.format(stdout.decode('cp949')) #first stdout

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the fact that the exe files with the same content are invoked. You can install python pip install x or conda pip install x or vs python pip install x sometimes.